# Is there a way to share part of a shared_ptr in different ranges?

Tags: c++, c++17, shared-ptr, unique-ptr

So, if you wanted to share everything in a `shared_ptr` past element `x` you could write something like the following:

```cpp
int main(){
    std::shared_ptr<float[]> _vals = std::make_unique<float[]>(70);
    for(uint32_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        _vals[i] = i;
    //range from 2 - end of _vals
    // x = 2 in this case
    std::shared_ptr<float[]> _partial(_vals, &_vals[2]);
    
    for(uint32_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        std::cout<<_partial[i]<<" ";
    std::cout<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

so the output would be:

```
2 3 4 5 6
```

So `_partial` would point from `_vals.get() + 2` to the end of `_vals`. However what if I wanted to have it point to for example `(2-5), (70-end)` for example, I was wondering if I could assign addresses to `_partial` to accomplish this?
So if for example this worked:

```cpp
int main(){
    std::shared_ptr<float[]> _vals = std::make_unique<float[]>(70);
    for(uint32_t i = 0; i < 70; ++i)
        _vals[i] = i;
    //range from 2 - 5, and then range from 70-73
    std::shared_ptr<float[]> _partial(_vals, &_vals[2]);
    float** begin = &(&_vals[70]);
    float** end = &(&_vals[73]);
    float** beg_2 = &(&_partial[2]);
    for(;begin != end; ++(*begin), ++(*beg_2)){
        beg_2 = begin;
    }

    //so technically _partial[0] would point to _vals[2] but _partial[3] would point to _vals[70]
    for(uint32_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        std::cout<<_partial[i]<<" ";
    std::cout<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

However, if I try to compile this, I get the error:

```
cannot take the address of an rvalue of type 'float *'
        float** begin = &(&_vals[70]);
```

Is there a way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Comment: It's legal to take the address of an array one past, but not legal to dereference it (because it's past the last valid element).  It's not legal to take `&_vals[73]` since that's is well past the end, even if it isn't dereferenced.  Was that an oversight in the provided example code?

Comment: *"However what if I wanted to have it point to for example `(2-5), (70-end)` for example"* -- Since you allocated 70 elements for `_vals`, index 70 is already the end. So `(2-5), (70-end)` is the same as `(2-5)`. Perhaps you want to change `70-end` to `60-end`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `shared_ptr` is the wrong tool for this job. A `shared_ptr` owns some object and points to some (potentially different) object. It does *not* implement enough logic to perform a mapping like `0 -> 0, 1 -> 1, 2 -> 2, 3 -> 70` like you want. (Nor *should* it implement this logic. It's not a simple task.)

Implement your own class to implement this behavior. This should get you started:

```
template<typename T>
class subsequence {
public:
    struct interval { std::size_t begin, length; };
private:
    std::shared_ptr<T[]> storage;
    std::vector<interval> pieces;
public:
    subsequence(std::shared_ptr<T[]> storage, std::initializer_list<interval> pieces)
    : storage(std::move(storage)), pieces(pieces) { }

    T &operator[](std::size_t i) {
        for(interval const &piece : pieces) {
            if(i < piece.length) return storage[piece.begin + i];
            else i -= piece.length;
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    std::size_t const size = 80;
    std::shared_ptr<float[]> vals = std::make_unique<float[]>(size);
    for(uint32_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) _vals[i] = i;

    subsequence partial(vals, {{2, 3}, {70, 3}}); // range from 2 - 5, and then range from 70-73
    for(uint32_t i = 0; i < 6; ++i) std::cout << partial[i] << " ";
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If the scatter spans need to be shared pointers of the original array, you can capture that information in shared pointer pairs, and then put those in a vector of those pairs.

I took the liberty of making the original array 99 elements, so the second span would be valid.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

using std::cout;
using std::exchange;
using std::ostream;
using std::pair;
using std::shared_ptr;
using std::vector;

namespace {

using shared_float_span = pair<shared_ptr<float>, shared_ptr<float>>;
using vector_span = vector<shared_float_span>;

auto operator<<(ostream& out, shared_float_span const& s) -> ostream& {
    auto sep = "";
    auto it = s.first.get();
    auto end = s.second.get();

    while (it != end) {
        out << exchange(sep, " ") << *it;
        ++it;
    }

    return out;
}

auto operator<<(ostream& out, vector_span const& v) -> ostream& {
    auto sep = "";

    for (auto&& x : v) {
        out << exchange(sep, " ") << x;
    }

    return out;
}

} // anon

int main(){
    shared_ptr<float[]> vals = std::make_unique<float[]>(99);

    for(uint32_t i = 0; i < 99; ++i) {
        vals[i] = 1000 + i;
    }

    shared_float_span a{ shared_ptr<float>(vals, &vals[2]), shared_ptr<float>(vals, &vals[6]) };
    shared_float_span b{ shared_ptr<float>(vals, &vals[70]), shared_ptr<float>(vals, &vals[74]) };
    vector_span v{a, b};
    cout << v << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Smart pointers are all about ownership - who owns the piece of memory you allocated?  You can't have one smart pointer own the entire array, and another own just a piece of it, it's physically impossible.

Comment: However, ownership could be split to subintervals. However, this is not implemented in.std::shared_ptr.

Comment: There are no fundamental reasons why multiple overlapping std::shared_ptrs cannot own an array together. However, this is not implemented.

Comment: @HTNW you're right, that code snippet appears to use a feature of `shared_ptr` that was only introduced with C++20.  But that form of the constructor does a *move* from the original `shared_ptr`, so the later accesses to the original pointer would be invalid.

Comment: @MarkRansom The form of the aliasing constructor used in the OP doesn't move.

Comment: @HTNW my apologies.  I was using [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr) as my guide, and it's kind of unclear that there are *two* versions of the constructor that take the unrelated parameter.

Answer (score 0):

> So `_partial` would point from `_vals.get() + 2` to the end of `_vals`.

No. A pointer points to a single object, not a range. In your case, `_partial` points to `_vals.get() + 2`. Just the one element. The idea that this gives access to a certain sub-range of `_vals` is based upon conventions you adopted for how to access elements.

Case in point: your loop printed the third through seventh elements of `_vals`. Your text suggests that the loop should have gone "to the end of `_vals`" (the 70th element), but it did not. Why? Because your loop ended at index 5 instead of 68. This is not something intrinsic to `_partial` but a result of how you used `_partial`.

Similarly, your loop started at index 0 (of `_partial`). This was your choice. While starting at index 0 is conventional, it is only conventional. In your particular case, `_partial` points to the third element of an array. This means that the expression `_partial.get()[-2]` is legal and points to the first element of the array. (The expression `_partial[-2]` probably also works in practice, but cppreference.com says the behavior is undefined.) Your starting point, like your ending point, is not something intrinsic to `_partial` but a result of how you used `_partial`.

The upshot is that the behavior you want is not about ownership but about how to use the data you have.

### Re-frame the question

So we can eliminate shared ownership from your question. You have an array, and you want a way to iterate over a sub-range of the array. It does not matter how the array is owned; the question requires just the existence of an array and a way to specify a sub-range.

The simple case is when the sub-range is contiguous. In this case, the sub-range can be specified by its beginning and end. A common way to do this is to provide a pointer to the beginning (`_partial`) and a size (`5` if we go by your loop, or `68` if we go wtih "the end of `_vals`"). You know how to do this. Your question is how to specify a non-contiguous sub-range.

The problem you face with a non-contiguous range is that `std::shared_ptr::operator[]` and the built-in `[]` operator are designed for contiguous ranges. The objects `_partial[2]` and `_partial[3]` must be in adjacent memory locations. That is how this operator works.

### Answers

So what can be done? In C++17, you could write an adapter class. Such a class could wrap an array and provide an `operator[]` that does what you want. That is, it would have a data member for array access (e.g. your `std::shared_ptr<float[]>`), and it would somehow store the indices for which you want access. I'll leave the details to the reader (or other answers) because it took so long for this answer to get to this point.

While this question is tagged C++17, I'll note that in C++20, there are ranges. In particular, a [filter view](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/filter_view) can be used to select which elements of an underlying view you want. For example, you could give a filter view a predicate that passes (returns `true`) when the address of the parameter minus `_vals` is between 2 and 5 or between 60 and 65. I'll leave the details to the reader because the question asked for a pre-20 answer.